# Preconfigure Android Emulator with location?

Tags: android, unit-testing, location, android-emulator

I want to run automated tests with location on the android emulator.
I can setup coordinates via Telnet, but that means starting up a console and manually configuring the emulator before running my junit tests.

Is there a possibility to preconfigure the emulator with a KML file or something like that to ensure that there are always coordinates available?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [LocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(String provider, Location loc)](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#setTestProviderLocation%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.Location%29) from within your tests already?